# Display title on checkbox hover over in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, simple-form

I am struggling with what I thought was a simple issue. I want to give a checkbox a title, alt or similar so that when I hover over the checkbox I will be given some specific information.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/adrianmann/Lwxhw71h/) is a jsfiddle example for text or a code example below (both in HTML) for what I am trying to achieve for a checkbox in ruby.

```
<span title="I am hovering over the text">This is the text I want to have a mousover</span>
```

I am specifically looking for a ruby solution for the code below, if there is one. Thanks.

```
<p>
  <%= f.association :study_role_permission_definitions, as: :check_boxes, label_method: :display_name  %>
</p>
```

Comment: Are you building the span via a rails html helper?  If so, can you add that code to your question?  If you're not, and you're just writing out the html in your erb template (or whatever), just do it as you have done it there.

Comment: Also, your jsfiddle example seems to be working fine, so please explain what your actual problem is :)

Comment: @Max Williams Yep, the js fiddle is working fine, I was just showing an example to clarify what I am looking for, I will add the code that I want to add a title etc. to now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but in Simple Form you can manipulate the HTML of the input field itself or the whole wrapper with the following options:

```
f.input :username, input_html: { title: 'My hover text' }
f.input :username, wrapper_html: { title: 'My hover text' }
```

I haven't tested it but it should work with `f.association`, too.

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you @Sebastion vom Meer. I used wrapper_html instead of input_html as I feel it is more natural to hover over either the checkbox or text rather than the checkbox alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= content_tag(:check_box, "label_text", :class => "class_name", :title => "your_span_content", data: {tooltip: true} %>
```

I hope this help you.